# Shape Recognition and finding the location

Tags: ros, object-recognition, laserscan, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Everyone,

I have a 3d point cloud data of human head. I have attached few markers (sphere/hemispheres) to the head before scanning the head with laser scanner. I need to find the location (xyz coordinates) of these markers. I was wondering if anyone could help in identifying these markers through shape/pattern recognition or any other technique so that I get the location of the markers. Does this software package has the capability of doing this? Thanks in advance.

Thanks
Santosh

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9523/shape-recognition-and-finding-the-location/) by [santosh](https://answers.ros.org/users/328/santosh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-03-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't looked at the implementation myself but perhaps the [shape_detection](http://www.ros.org/wiki/shape_detection) package from the [object_recognition](http://www.ros.org/wiki/object_recognition) stack is a solution?

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-10-28**:
Where  is shape_detection doc details? It seems nothing... Thank you~